# Scraping websites with Python3 (Scrapy, BS4) does yield incomplete data. Can not figure out why

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Some time ago I have set up a web scraper using BS4, logging the value of a whisky each day

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

def getPrice() -> float:
    try:
        URL = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/2940/suntory-yamazaki-12-year-old"
        website = requests.get(URL)
    except:
        print("ERROR requesting Price")
    
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
        price = str(soup.find("p", class_="product-action__price").next)
        price = float(price[1::])
        return price
    except:
        print("ERROR parsing Price")
```

This worked as intended. The request contained the complete website and the correct value was extracted.

I was now trying to scrape other sites for data on other whiskys this time using SCRAPY.

I tried the following URLS:

https://www.thegrandwhiskyauction.com/past-auctions/q-macallan/180-per-page/relevance

https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&LH_Complete=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=10&_fpos=&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_fosrp=1&_nkw=macallan&rt=nc

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "whisky"

    def start_requests(self):
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
        urls = [
            'https://www.thegrandwhiskyauction.com/past-auctions/q-macallan/180-per-page/relevance',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'whisky-{page}.html'
        #data = response.css('.itemDetails').getall()
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
```

I just customized the basic example from the tutorial to create the fast prototype above.
However it did not return the complete website. The body of the response did miss several tags and especially the content I was looking for.

I tried to solve this with BS4 again like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.thegrandwhiskyauction.com/past-auctions/q-macallan/180-per-page/relevance"
website = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')

with open("whiskeySoup.html", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup.body))
```

To my surprise this produced the same result. The request and its body did not contain the complete website, missing all the data I was looking for.

I also included a user-agent header since I learned that some sites recognize requests from bots and spiders and do not deliver all their data. However, this did not solve the problem.

I am unable to figure out or debug why the data requested from those URLs is incomplete.
Is there a way to solve this using SCRAPY?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of websites heavily relies on javascript to generate the final html page of website. When you send request to server it returns html code with some script web browsers like chrome, Firefox and others process that javascript code and the final html that you can see appears. But when you are using scrapy, request or some library they do not come with the functionality of executing the javascript code and hence the html code is different in html, and as the crawler sees the webpage.
If you want to see how crawler sees the website ( the html code of webpage as seen by crawler ) you can run command 'scrapy view {url}' this will open page in browser or if you want to get the html code of webpage as seen by crawler you can run command 'scrapy fetch {url}'. When you are working with scrapy it is good idea to open the url in shell ( the command is 'scrapy shell {url}' ) and then test your extracting desired content logic there with xpath or css method ( response.css('some_css').css('again_some_css'). ) and then finally add this logic to your final crawler. If you want to see what response you got in shell. you can just type view(response) and it will open the response received in browser. I hope that is clear. But if you want to process the javascript before finally processing the response ( when it is necessary ) you can use selenium which is headless browser or splash which is lightweight web browser. selenium is pretty easy to use.

Edit 1. For the first url : go to scrapy shell and check the css path div.bidPrice::text. Inside that you will see that content inside is generated dynamically and there is no html code and content is being generated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still a bit confused. Trying for the first URL I mentioned, scrapy view {url} and  scrapy shell {url} + view(response) both display the website correctly meaning populated with all the data I am looking for. The Price is correctly available via css path div.bidPrice::text in the browser preview of the response. However response.css("div.bidPrice::text").getall() does only return some "\n".

Comment: in scrapy shell run response.css('div.bidPrice').get() here you will see the first div block as it is fetched by the crawler. here the bid price and other text inside box is not present instead there are some variables like %bid_descriptor_text% %multi_currency% and such. But when the same html code is viewed from web browser I think there must be some script inside the html code code ( added with <script> tag ) which gets executed when this code is opened with browser. but when running from shell \n is only text present inside that div. I think selenium is necessary here.